# Opacity for the background, not font

Tags: html, css, fonts, background-image, opacity

Hi I have searched in previous questions and tried multiple ways but I still have trouble setting up opacity of my background image without effecting opacity of font.

this is my html:

```
<main>
    <div class="background">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="center">
                <h1>My name</h1>
                <h3>this is my website</h3>
                <hr>
                <button id = "mainButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Get Started!</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </main>
```

and this is css:

```
 .background{
    background-image: url("xxx.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

*I tried to use rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

*I tried to set up another css rule just for h1, or the div with the text but still the same.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Use absolute position on two separate Elements inside a relative position container.

Answer (score 1):

Make the markup like this:

```
<main>
    <div class="background">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    </div>
</main>
```

Give to `main` `position: relative;`

Give to background div `position: absolute;`

Fix the rest. You're done.

**About background size**

You can modify the image background size by `background-size` and using values like `cover`, `contain`, `100%`, `100% 100%` etc.

If you want to cover all the page, use value `100vh`, meaning 100% of the viewport height.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this before. This solution works for font but then my background photo covers only the div tag not a whole page. The height is set up to 100% i can use px but then I am worried its not responsive anymore. Do you have any thought about that please?

Comment: Oh great! Your solution works and now with the 100vh my image is covering whole page! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Glad to help. Remember to upvote and accept my answer.